# cluster of services and restarting on package upgrade

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet to manage a bunch of servers. Those servers run a simple service - exposed to the world via load balancer. That service's instances are independent in that they can run on their own, are are deployed on multiple servers to increase responsiveness.

Now, when I push a new package to repo and puppet catches up with it appearing there it just updates this package on all services. This results in a short downtime of entire service.

Is there a way of configuring puppet to do restart the services sequentially? Or using any other kind of strategy?

Comment: Are you asking how to *splay* your puppet runs?

Comment: It seems so. According to this http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/orchestration_puppet.html splay is on by default - am I right? even when reinstalling packages?

Comment: Can you outline the relationship between servers, services and packages? Numbers help. How many servers, how many packages, and what happens during a package update through puppet?

Comment: Actually what I've wanted to do is this: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/orchestration_puppet.html#run-puppet-on-many-nodes-in-a-controlled-series

Answer (score 0):

What is needed in this case is MCollective extension for puppet as described in the [official documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2018.1/controlling_puppet.html#running_puppet_on_many_nodes_in_a_controlled_series).

This is sufficient for my use case.